# How to collect all the elements into one?

Tags: c++, string, vector, integer

My code parses an integer into parts and writes them to an array, but now I want to collect the array back into an integer.

I will modify the data inside the array so I need to collect everything back after the changes.

```
int a = 123456789;
std::string stringInt = std::to_string(a);

std::vector<int> numbers;
numbers.reserve(stringInt.length());

for (const auto& chr : stringInt)
{
    // ...

    numbers.push_back(chr - '0');
    cout << chr << "\n" << endl;
}
```

Comment: And your question is...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add up the integers, multiplying the result by `10` every time:

```
int b = 0;
for (const auto& chr : stringInt)
{
    numbers.push_back(chr - '0');
    b *= 10;
    b += chr - '0';
}
std::cout << b << std::endl;
```

Alternatively you can put the chars into a string instead of turning them into `int` and putting them into a vector and then use `std::stoi` to get an `int` back out of the string:

```
std::string numbers;
for (const auto& chr : stringInt)
{
    numbers.push_back(chr);
    cout << chr << "\n" << endl;
}
int b = std::stoi(numbers);
std::cout << b << std::endl;
```

Comment: I like the second example, but I don’t know yet if I can count without using an array.

Comment: can I do something like this?
`chr++;`

Comment: @chip you can do that. Just beware since it's a `char`, increasing it when its value is `'9'` will make it not be a valid digit anymore.

Comment: Got it, thanks, does the for loop turn everything into a char?
Is it possible to change to int for example?

Comment: @chip In this loop, `chr` is a `char` because `std::string` is a container for `char` so to speak, so when you iterate over its elements, you get chars. Of course you can assign `chr` to an `int` variable or otherwise convert it to something else. It's all good as long as the elements that you put in the other container are correct. For instance, if `numbers` should be an `std::string` that only contains numbers, then you can only add chars to it that represent numbers.

Comment: thanks, if I use `int64_t` I need to use `stoll(numbers);` right?

Comment: @chip That's right. Assuming that `int64_t` correspondents to `long long` on your machine, which it most likely does. `stoi` would still work with `int64_t` as long as the number would fit into an `int` (there would be an implicit cast), but `stoll` can handle bigger numbers than `stoi`.